# TypeScript: Assign value to field name in variable

Tags: typescript

I need to

```
type A {
  f1: string;
  f2; string;
}
```

By other side I have a variable contains the field name:

```
let fieldName: string = "f2";
```

I'd like to create an object using `fieldName`:

```
{"content of fieldName": "sdf"}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of ES2015 you can use [computed properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015).

For your example that would mean:

```
{ [fieldName]: "sdf" }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `{[fieldName]:'sdf'}`. Here is a [blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-4qko8k)